# Create an array from grapEdge and print

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, graph, review

I want stamp facebook reviews of my page in an array. I'm try this code:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook/src/Facebook/autoload.php'; // change path as needed

$config = array();
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'appid',
  'app_secret' => 'appsecret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
  'default_access_token' => 'accesstoken', // optional

  ]);
      $page_id='228658763935080';
      $request = $fb->request('GET', '/'.$page_id.'/');
    // Send the request to Graph

/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get(
    '228658763935080/ratings?fields=open_graph_story&access_token=accesstoken'
  );
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
$graphEdge= $graphEdge->asArray();
print_r($graphEdge);

echo "<table>";

foreach ($graphEdge as $review) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $review['value'] . " of " . $review['scale'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td> Reviews:</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $review['review_text'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
  echo "</table>";  

    ?>
```

But not work. I've stamp result of array https://allevamentochihuahua.com/recensioni2.php to show you the structure.
In order I'm need insert a name and surname of person that write reviews.. but I don't find in graph stamped..

can you help me?

Comment: please do not post results as a php file that may not be available in the future. always add debug results directly on stackoverflow, with code. it is not even available now anymore, because the session expired. this thread will still exist in several years, so make sure it does not depend on external stuff.

Comment: I've created now extended token, sorry.
Now you can view results ;)

Comment: again, do not use an external script for debug infos....post the debug infos on stackoverflow